# Validation of a date with a given format in Matlab

Tags: validation, datetime, matlab

I am designing a GUI. I have an edit text box where I enter a date string with the following format '31 Mar 2011 10:00:00.000'. I need code to validate it and write an error message in case of invalid input. Thank you for your attention. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you handle this with a regular expression.  If you will require your user to input a date with a specific format, I could see parsing this string with the matlab function regexp to see if it matches a given format.  In the case you gave above something like

```
s='31 Mar 2011 10:00:00.000'
regexp(s,'\d{1,2} \w{3} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.?\d*')
```

could be used to see if your date matches the format.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have chosen it because I think it is the most simple and easy. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap a `datenum` in a `try`-`catch`, like this:

```
try
    a=datenum('lkdsldkjhfsg');
catch
    disp('Bad date')
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my own case, I have had to use the command datevec in conjunction with a try-catch statement. I do not know which answer accept because my solution is a mix of both.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [`datestr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datestr.html), [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html), the [predefined date formats](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bspgcx2-1.html#bsplnu3-4) and [symbolic identifiers for the fields](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bspgcx2-1.html#bsplnu3-2). You can then build a validation around each of the identifiers by checking to see if it satisfies certain criteria. You can use [`error`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/error.html) to throw an error to the user in case of invalid input.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my own case, I have had to use the command datevec in conjunction with a try-catch statement. I do not know which answer accept because my solution is a mix of both.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the answers. This is one of the posible callback function codes corresponding to the edit text box that it can be used:

```
user_entry = get(hObject,'string');
control = regexp(user_entry,'\d{1,2} \w{3} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.?\d*')
if(numel(control)==0)
    errordlg('Invalid Input Format','Error Message','modal')
    uicontrol(hObject)
end
```